# How to Convert Vue 2 x to Vue 3 x?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

We are integrating Vue into an existing ASP.Net MVC Application

Below  code (Vue 2 X)working fine in our .Net Application

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#component1',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

To convert Vue 2 X to Vue 3 X used command "vue add vue-next" , after executing command version changed  but  "npm run build" command giving error.

Comment: Just read and follow the migration guide: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Vue 3 migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html) to help with the upgrade. It shims most of the Vue 2 code, while emitting console warnings that help you identify what to migrate.

To enable it in your Vue CLI project (based on [installation steps from the migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html#installation)), and to fix the code you mentioned:

1. Update `vue` to 3.1, and install `@vue/compat` of the same version:

   ```bash
   npm i -S @vue/compat@^3.1.4
   npm i -S vue@^3.1.4
   ```
2. Setup an alias from `vue` to `@vue/compat`:

   ```js
   // vue.config.js
   module.exports = {
     chainWebpack: config => {
       config.resolve.alias.set('vue', '@vue/compat')
     }
   }
   ```
3. Update the app entry to the [new global mounting API](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#a-new-global-api-createapp):

   ```js
   // import Vue from 'vue'
   // import App from './App.vue'
   // new Vue({ el: '#component1', render: h => h(App) });

   import { createApp } from 'vue'
   import App from './App.vue'
   createApp(App).mount('#component1')
   ```